# Could not find type” error loading a form in the Windows Forms Designer

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2012, windows

I have a windows form where I have created my own custom comboBox code .cs class file in my project and used that in my form controls.

This works fine for the exsisting project where its been created.

Problem:
The same form and controls needs to be inherited in an another project(solution)...

When I copied mycombo.class file and the rest of the forms to the other project solution I get the below error....

> Could not find type 'namespace.MyCombobox'. Please make sure that the assembly that contains this type is referenced. If this type is a
>   part of your development project, make sure that the project has been
>   successfully built using settings for your current platform or Any
>   CPU.
>
> The variable 'comboBox_BusinessType' is either undeclared or was never assigned.

It is working fine when running the file but when I open the desiner.cs file the error is occuring particularly for the combobox controls in the designer.cs files of all the forms copied.

Is there any soltuion for this issue ? Please let me know if any further information is required to solve this one....

Comment: This is silly...but have you closed out of visual studio and re-opened the solution?  I have had similar issues and it just needs to clear some cache it has.

Comment: I tired to clean , rebuild, close and reopen the solution for N number of times but still the issue exsist...

Comment: Make sure your `MyCombo` class is `public`. Then you don't need to copy the `MyCombo.cs` to the new project. In your new project, just add a reference to the project that contains `MyCombo.cs` and then rebuild your solution and open your forms in design mode. It will work.

Comment: @RezaAghaei... thanks..ok let me try this one and let you know the result...

Comment: @RezaAghaei... the two project are entirely different and are kept in different soltuions... Is it still possible to add the references  ?

Comment: Yes it's possible after add existing project to the solution. **But** if the projects are completely different and are not related to each other, how can you want to reuse forms and controls from one in other?

Comment: no the functionality differes in each forms but the structure remains the same... I need to do modifications after imopting the forms..... I did what you said but still the issue persist....  I saw from another post like whether the comboBox been used from tool box ? and they did something to include the custom controls from tool box....

Comment: Can you suggest some other ideas to resolve this one ?

Comment: Unfortunately it's unclear for me what you are asking. Yes all public controls of referenced project are available through the toolbox and you can use them. But I don't know why you are copying forms and classes from one project to other project. Usually it will cause some problems because of different namespaces.

Comment: @RezaAghaei... thanks for your comments... I'm importing forms via 'add exsisiting item' process... yes it has issue with the name space but when we change the name it just resolves the issue with the namespace... but i'm not sure why the designer page is not getting opened....and im getting these errors for no reason....